# Motivation for Connections over smooth manifolds

Tags: derivatives, differential-geometry, euclidean-geometry, vector-bundles, connections

I was reading about connections on Wikipedia and I found this section about "Motivation":
[image]
My question is the following one. If I look at the vector bundle $E$ like a manifold, then locally I have charts and I can think of $X: M \rightarrow E$ like a smooth map between open subsets of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{R}^m$ for some $n$ and $m$. Hence, I should naturally have a definition of derivatives. Am I wrong? What is the point of that argument?

Thanks in advance

Comment: It’d take an actual geometer to explain why this is a problem, but, while your construction is correct, it heavily depends on the choice of charts and trivializations, so it’s not “geometric”.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the story below sound plausible, you should first convince yourself that any reasonable notion of differentiation is going to be a map $\nabla:\Gamma(E)\to\Gamma(T^*M\otimes E)$, with some additional properties. That is, given a section $s$, we get $\nabla s$, and we can feed it a vector field $\nabla_Xs$ to "differentiate in the direction of $X$". Furthermore, it should satisfy the Leibniz rule $\nabla(fs)=df\otimes s+f\nabla s$, and it should satisfy $\nabla_{fX}(s_1+s_2)=f(\nabla_Xs_1+\nabla_Xs_2)$. These are all properties satisfied by the usual derivative. More generally, $\nabla$ will be called a connection.

Let $E\to M$ be a vector bundle for which we want to define a connection. and let $U\subset M$ be a trivialising open subset, so we have $E|_U\cong U\times\mathbb{R}^r$ via a diffeomorphism $\Phi:E|_U\to U\times\mathbb{R}^k$ (which is fibrewise linear). Let's also suppose that $U$ is a chart, so we additionally have a diffeomorphism $\varphi:U\to\varphi(U)\subset\mathbb{R}^n$. Let $s\in\Gamma(E)$ and $v\in T_xM$. Then we can say that $\varphi\times\text{id}\circ\Phi\circ s\circ \varphi^{-1}:\varphi(U)\to U\to E|_U\to U\times\mathbb{R}^r\to\varphi(U)\times\mathbb{R}^r$ which can be identified with a function $f:\varphi(U)\to\mathbb{R}^r$, and you are suggesting that we use the linear structure on $\varphi(U)\times\mathbb{R}^r$. As you can tell from the number of arrows I wrote, there are a lot of identifications to be made to try to do this, in the first place, which is a good indication that such a construction is, at any rate, not instrinsic - if it possible at all.

After making these identifications, we can locally define
$$ds(v)_x=\lim_{t\to 0}\frac{s(\gamma(t))-s(\gamma(0))}{t}$$
I have neglected to write out the various chart maps and left the identifications implicit. What we've done here, is defining an element $ds\in \Gamma(T^*U\otimes E|_U)$. It takes a tangent vector (or vector field) and gives us a new section of $E|_U$. If you read a bit more about connections, you will find the definition of the local connection $1$-form $A\in\Gamma(U,\text{End}(E|_U))$ which in our case is $0$, as it is the $1$-form such that $\Phi\circ\nabla\circ\Phi^{-1}=d+A$, and you wanted to define a derivative in the "naive" way. Why does such a $1$-form $A$ exist? It exists because the difference between any two connections lies in $\Gamma(T^*M\otimes \text{End}(E))$. You can verify this by hand quite easily, using the Leibniz rule. On the trivialisation, we the naive connection $d$, which you want to define globally (denoted $\nabla$), and so there exists $A\in\Gamma(T^*U\otimes\text{End}(E|_U))$ such that $\Phi\circ\nabla\circ\Phi^{-1}-d=A$, i.e. $\Phi\circ\nabla\circ\Phi^{-1}=d+A$.

In order to really give a connection with the properties that you would expect of a derivative, the local $1$-form must satisfy
$$A_V=\Psi^{-1}\circ A_U\circ\Psi+\Psi^{-1}d\Psi$$
for any trivialising $V\subset M$ with $U\cap V\neq\emptyset$, where $\Psi$ is the transition function between $U\times\mathbb{R}^r$ and $V\times\mathbb{R}^r$. Does the naive definition satisfy this rule? The answer is clearly no, because we would have $A_V=0\neq \Psi^{-1}d\Psi$. That is, unless $d\Psi=0$, which generally is not the case.